# How are consecutive if statements evaluated?

Tags: swift, swift4

I have two if-statements to check, where one check is very costly. So I'm wondering which of the following statements would be the most performant:

1) I don't like the "pyramid of doom", but I'm sure it works fine

```
for customObject in array {
    if customObject.isSimpleBool {
        if customObject.isCostlyBool {
            // do some stuff
        }
    }
}
```

2) I normally write like this ... but does it check `isCostlyBool`, if `isSimpleBool` is `false`?

```
for customObject in array {
    if customObject.isSimpleBool && customObject.isCostlyBool {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

3) I know this works, but is it evaluated differently than solution 2?

```
for customObject in array {
    if customObject.isSimpleBool, customObject.isCostlyBool {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

4) Is there another solution I have not found?

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32726723/is-there-an-operator-in-swift-that-stops-the-evaluation-of-a-multi-expression-co.

Comment: solution 2 will work, swift will stop evaluating as soon as it knows the answer to the expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for customObject in array {
    if customObject.isSimpleBool && customObject.isCostlyBool {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

This will work, I have used these kinds of statements with nil checks many times.

```
if (obj != nil && obj!.property == false) {}
```

and in cases of `obj` being nil, `obj.property` is never called(otherwise the application would crash)

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
array.filter { $0.isSimpleBool && $0.isCostlyBool }
     .forEach { // do some stuff }
```

By the way: Solution 2 and 3 are different forms for the same thing.

Comment: Hi vadian, I like this approach. However the fact that here we are performing 2 loops (one for filtering and one for the "do stuff" part) is a concern by a performance point of view?

Comment: Could be. I'm not sure that `forEach` is performing a loop under the hood. Maybe the compiler is so smart to *merge* the two functions. A benchmark test could figure it out.

Comment: An under the hood optimization would be very nice

Comment: Would be indeed nice to know if this is as performant as the `&&`-solution.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in there comments, if we have boolean expression like this

```
a && b
```

and a is `false` then the result is evaluated as false only evaluating `a`.

### So...

```
isSimpleBool && isCostlyBool
```

is evaluated as `false` without evaluating `isCostlyBool` when `isSimpleBool` is `false`.

This is a good reason why you should put the `isSimpleBool` value at the **left** side of the `&&` operator.

### Another syntax

Finally just another way of writing the same logic

```
for elm in array where elm.isSimpleBool && elm.isCostlyBool {
    // do some stuff
}
```

Comment: The solution you provided as "another syntax" is the one I'll use, thanks. Performant while being even shorter and not less understandable :)